# IDataReader vs DataTable; pros and cons

Tags: c#, datatable, sqlbulkcopy, idatareader

I am working on doing a large scale insert/update operation.

So I am using `SqlBulkCopy`.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);

try
{
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlBulkCopy myCommand = new SqlBulkCopy(myConnection);

    myCommand.DestinationTableName = "myDestinationTableName";

    //Below method has four overloads; 
    //of which I am interested in the two mentioned below.
    myCommand.WriteToServer();

    myCommand.Close();
}
finally
{
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

But I stumbled upon these two versions of `WriteToServer` method.

1. [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer Method (IDataReader)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer Method (DataTable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Question : What are the pros and cons of one over another? Which one is faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the default case, both should have similar performance otherwise [horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)..

But there is one difference though, `WriteToServer` with `DataTable` as parameter will insert all rows from `DataTable` , but with `IDataReader` copy starts with next available row in the reader *(which would be set to first row in default case)*.

Remember, `IDataReader` provides a read-only/forward only mechanism, so there is a concept of current position/row index, whereas with `DataTable` there is no such thing. With each `Read` on `IDataReader` row index moves to next row.

Answer (score 1):

Overload with `DataTable` is intended for the cases, when you already have suitable `DT` somewhere in your application.

Overload with `IDataReader`, in turn, is for the cases, when there is some query (either raw query text, or constructed command, it doesn't matter). In this case, creation of intermediate data container, such as `DT`, is unnecessary. Hence, this overload allows you to fetch data directly from reader.

Assuming, that you haven't neither `DT`, nor `IDataReader`, the second one should at least consume less resources.